# Azure Point-to-Site VPN - cannot connect to virtual machines in peered VNets

Tags: azure, routes, vpn, vnet

I have the following in Azure:

- HubVNet with VPN Gateway (Point to Site VPN)
- Spoke01VNet with one virtual machine
- HubVNet and Spoke01VNet are peered with gateway transit enabled
- Spoke01VNet is allowing forwarded traffic from HubVNet

I connect to VPN Gateway from my workstation successfully.  I have a virtual machine on HubVNet (same as VPN Gateway) and I can successfully RDP to that server (I use it as a jumpbox right now) and can successfully RDP to server in Spoke01VNet from that jumpbox server.

I would like to RDP to server in Spoke01VNet from my workstation but cannot connect.  I thought by peering the VNets would allow this to happen when I connected via VPN but not so.  Can anyone provide me some assistance on how to do this, if it's possible with a Point-to-Site VPN?  Thank you in advance for all your help!!

Comment: How do you set the VNet peering? Can you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if you have correctly configured your Hub-spoke network topology in Azure. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke#virtual-network-peering) for more details.

- Configure the peering connection in the hub to `allow gateway transit`.
- Configure the peering connection in each spoke to `use remote gateways`.
- Configure all peering connections to `allow forwarded traffic`.

Once the VNet peering is connected, you could re-download your VPN client package to re-connect the VPN connection on your local machine. This might make the update network effect.

Comment: That was it!!!!  After I  created the Peer, I had to re-download the client and install and I'm now able to connect to that VM in the Spoke VNet from my desktop.  Thank you so much!